# I can not identify a specific xpath for to select a button using Selenium front-end React

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I am trying to uniquely identify and select a radio button {YES,NO} under a specific question.Since the developers are using React it is difficult for me to identify the specific buttons.In the developer tools, in the label class children i see the radio button with the unique name. However when i try to identify the name using xpath `"//*[contains(@name,"ID_2")]`, or "//*[contains(@id,"ID_2-1")]`  the chrome developer identifies the path, but the yes or no fields are not highlighted. When i hover over the parent class for the text "Yes" parent -   the Yes button is highlighted. The issue i am having is, how can i uniquely identify this class so i can click on the button? I have tried using the absolute path, which works.Eventually that will break. If I use a simple xpath of (@class = "label__radio"), the developer will point to over 50 occurrences. I will greatly appreciate any suggestions

I am not sure which other direction to go since i cannot identify the field.

Html Code example:
[image]

[Showing the Yes button being highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz6nt.png)

Comment: Did you try XPath in code? Any exceptions? What is the point of leading double-quotes?

Comment: While you were writing your question i have updated my post. If i run the code pointing to the name= ID__2 i run into a error No element found

Comment: Check whether radio-button located inside an frame/iframe or try to implement [Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: I figured out how to dynamically identify the field. //*[(@class = "label__question") and (text() = "Is Patient Using Donor Egg?")]//../child::*//*[contains(@class,"label__radio") and contains(text(),"Yes")]